# The path does not exist (Eclipse + Java)

Tags: java, eclipse

Версия Ubuntu 18.04.2
openjdk - 11.0.3
[image: Постоянно получаю эту ошибку]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже перепробовал разные способы в интернете, однако все безуспешно. Пишет, что такого файла не существует, однако он есть. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: ну и что вам не ясно, [всё написано же](https://i.imgur.com/nTKnsF1.png)?

Comment: @tym32167 я пытаюсь изменить путь, однако ошибку выдает, что файл не существует, но он есть.

Comment: Вы пишете путь руками или выбираете файл через `External File....` ?

Comment: @tym32167 выбираю

Comment: zip архив исходников размером 21 байт?

Comment: @tym32167 да, странно... Но я после скачивания ничего не трогал.

Comment: ну так распакуйте файл и поглядите, что внутри. Он скорее всего порченный и в нем проблема.

Comment: @tym32167я с ним ничего не могу сделать, пишет, что файл не существует. Я решил переустановить jdk и получаю всю ту же ошибку.

Comment: ну так вы качаете тот же порченный файл из того же места и ожидаете другой результат? У меня подобный файл [весит 6 с лишним метров](https://i.imgur.com/UeKbcON.png)

Comment: @tym32167 я скачал уже с другого места

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла вот эта команда

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-source`